# SQL statement not filtering rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

The following code passes this row. The last column is named `toscode`. I am trying to weed out rows whose `toscolumn` contains "W1" anywhere in the name. No columns are set up as an index. Doesn't work.

I read that the `$` (escape) in front of `W1` is to prevent SQL injection. Not sure what the `%` do, but it might have to do with indexes which is maybe why it doesn't work.

```
| SPX    |   0 |    8.3 |    8.7 | 2017-03-24 |               0 |   30 | PUT |   2400 | SPXW170324C02400000 | .SPXW1703242400 |

MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbol", symbol);
cmd.CommandText = @"select * 
                    from contractdetails 
                    where symbol = @symbol 
                       && toscode NOT LIKE '%$W1%'
                       && Type = 'PUT' 
                       && oBid > .09 
                       && not ITM  
                       && Days > 10 
                       && Days < 120 
                    order by Days asc";
```

Comment: If you're trying to select only rows that contain "W1", you should use `LIKE`, not `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly *I am trying to **weed out** rows whose `toscolumn` does not contain "W1" anywhere in the name.*

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not if "weed out" means "exclude".

Comment: @RiggsFolly If OP wants to **exclude** rows **without** "W1", then he wants to **include** only rows **with** "W1". Not sure how else to put it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Either you're interpreting "weed out" as "select", or one of us has had too many drinks.

Comment: @shmosel I have only had one large _Rusty Nail_ :) How about you?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Getting started now.

Comment: @Ivan `%` is a wildcard which will match anything before and after "W1". I don't know what `$` is for, but you don't need to worry about SQL injection for your own hardcoded input.

Answer (score 2):

your `LIKE` clause should be:

```
toscode NOT LIKE '%W1%'
```

remove the '$' -it doesnt belong or have any meaning in a `LIKE` clause. You would only have to worry about SQL injection if it was user provided input, which in your example is not the case.

the '%' character is a wildcard, so anything could be before or after 'W1' in your search

Comment: That works, but what about "escaping to prevent SQL injection"? Not that I care that much...

Comment: Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)